# How to make navigation bar and table view position fixed while Keyboard scroll to bottom?

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard

I am working on the tableview controller with a textfield at the bottom. When it runs and I click the textfield, the whole page scrolls to the bottom including the navigation bar placed at the top. I want to take the navigation baR FIXED ON TOP and scrolling position of table view remain unchanged. Would you please tell me another way to change the tableview frame or other methods ? I am currently using iOS 11.0 for testing, Xcode 9.1 swift 4

```
import UIKit
import GRDB
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import Alamofire
import SVProgressHUD
import UIEmptyState
import SwiftyJSON


class AssistantController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource , UITextFieldDelegate , UIEmptyStateDelegate , UIEmptyStateDataSource  {

    var user : User!
    var assist : [Assistant] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init()

        let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), for: .normal)
        btn2.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 219.0/255.0, green: 103.0/255.0, blue: 93.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
        btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(compopen(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let item2 : UIBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(item2, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.title = "AssistMan".localized()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        txtEmail.placeholder = "Assistant Email (Optional)".localized()
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false


        txtEmail.delegate = self

        //txtEmail.becomeFirstResponder()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        //tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        if keyboardFrame.size.height <= 0 { // to fix bug on iOS 11
            keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        }
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
            tableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardFrame.height)

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {

        tableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = true
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { // called when 'return' key pressed. return {
        print("typed")
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        // add
        //executeInsert ()
        return true
    }

    func executeInsert () {

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        let assistantEmail : String = txtEmail.text!
        if assistantEmail.isEmpty {
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus:  "Please type your email".localized())
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 2.0)
            return
        }


    }

    @IBAction func executeAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        executeInsert ()
    }


    @objc func compopen (  sender: UIBarButtonItem ) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        user  = User.sharedInstance
        enqueue(subUrl: "GetAssistant", inputDict: user.getAssist())
        getData()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if assist.isEmpty {
            self.reloadEmptyStateForTableView(self.tableView)
            //self.emptyStateView?.tintColor = UIColor.themeRed()
        }
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
        return "刪除".localized()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return assist.count
    }



}
```

Comment: what is the relation between your question title and your question ?

Comment: I have got my title changed, sorry